# importing column having character numeric in sas

Tags: sas

I have two .csv files which i need to merge in sas.

The first file contains the data something like this :

```
column - products

3 - sales

3- sales
```

to more than 8 rows and then there are observations such as

00000ETH - sales

00000TRF - sales

The second file has data like this -

```
Columns - Products

3 - brand

4 - brand

0000ETH - brand

0000TRF - brand
```

Basically I have to make a new column "Brand" in the first file.

But when I import the first file , SAS makes the first observation as 000000003 while it remains as "3" in the second file. its taking the column as numeric because the first 8 rows are numeric in the first file

I have tried changing "TypeGuess rows" in the windows registry but it has not worked.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

If they're CSV files, TYPEGUESSROWS is not helpful as that is an excel setting.  You can modify GUESSINGROWS directly in the proc import instead.

Try reading it in with data step, however- then you don't need to GUESS anythng.

```
data one;
length column $10 products $25; *or whatever is right;
infile "yourfile.csv" dlm=',' dsd lrecl=100 truncover; *or similar depending on your file;
input column $ products $;
run;
```

Similar for the other dataset.